# pdfbox additionalGlyphs file can be used to add custom glyphs?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, glyph-substitution

I am trying to edit pdfbox source code to read pdfs with custom embeded fonts. My question is:
Can edit the code in pdfbox 2.0 to read from my glyphs from additionalGlyphs file by editing the file will this approach work?

PS: I have never edited or even studied the source code pdfbox java libraries.

Comment: *"Can edit the code in pdfbox 2.0 to read from my glyphs from additionalGlyphs file by editing the file will this approach work?"* - which information exactly do you have?

Comment: @mkl I have all the glyphs and font file.

Comment: Ok, and your want to *"read pdfs with custom embeded fonts"* - do you mean that you want to *extract the text from them*?

Comment: @mkl: exactly! I have font files but still extracted text reads the character from unicode and I want it from glyphs I provide.

Comment: Which data does your *additionalGlyphs* contain exactly?

Comment: @mkl mapping of glyphs which are not present or have miss matched mappings.

Comment: I meant exactly? CIDs to Unicode? Names to Unicode?

Comment: @mkl CID's to unicode

Comment: Then it should be possible to patch PDFBox accordingly. Can you share an example PDF and additionalGlyphs file?